# Communicating between subclassed nstextfield and view controller in swift

Tags: cocoa, size, subclass, viewcontroller, nstextfield

I've run into an issue where I need to communicate between a class that is a subclass of nstextfield and the view controller I am using in a cocoa swift project.

The subclassed nstextfield changes the size of it's frame. The field itself is within a table within the view controller. Essentially, when the nstextfield changes its frame size, I want the view controller to become aware of that. I'm able to signal to the view controller that the frame has changed via the use of Nsnotification Centre where an observer in the view controller listens for the notification, that works fine. But now when that notification is triggered, I need to view controller to return to the subclassed nstextfield in order to retrieve the size of the frame. I don't believe that I can pass for example a frame size with the notification message.

Can anyone give me an idea as to how I retrieve the frame size of the nstextfield from within the view controller?

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Do you send your own notification or do you use NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification?

Comment: Hi Willeke, I'm sending my own notification as follows             `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("adviseViewControllerTextboxChanged", object: nil)` which essentially triggers a function to handle the re-sizeing of that particular row in the table. My issue then becomes that I need to know within that function the size of the frame on the nstextfield in that particular row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post your notification you can specify an object, in this case the textfield. The viewcontroller can retrieve the textfield from notification.object and ask for its frame.

If the viewcontroller needs more info, you can use -postNotificationName:object:userInfo:, userinfo is a dictionary in which you can store whatever you want.

Comment: That solves my problem. Exactly what I was trying to sort out. Thanks Willeke!

Answer (score 0):

You should use extend the `NSTextFieldDelegate`-[protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) above your subclassed text field class with the custom method like

```
protocol MyCustomTextFieldDelegate: NSTextFieldDelegate
{
  func OnTextFieldSizeDidChange(sender:MyCustomTextField, newFrame:CGFrame)
}

class MyCustomTextField : NSTextField
{
//...
weak var customDelegate: MyCustomTextFieldDelegate?
}
```

Then just implement this protocol by the view controller and set `customDelegate`-property on text field init.

When your text field did change the frame, the method above should be called.